# How do I edit particular coulmn in QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

I want to display a table from Database and display it, But Also want to modify a particular column based on a function

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(parentObject, database);
    model->setTable("employee");
    model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    model->select();
    model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Name"));
    model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Salary"));
    model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("encrypted_item"));
    QTableView *view = new QTableView;
    view->setModel(model);
    view->hideColumn(0); // don't show the ID
    view->show();
```

But now instead of printing encrypted item , I want to decrypt and display it, How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `QSqlQueryModel` and set your desired query, but you know `QSqlQueryModel` is not editable. A solution is to subclass `QSqlQueryModel` and reimplement the `Qt::ItemFlags QAbstractItemModel::flags ( const QModelIndex & index ) const` method which returns a a set of flag where the `Qt::ItemIsEditable` is set. You can find a good example of editable `QSqlQueryModel` [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-querymodel.html).